# Share existing virtualbox vm across partitions

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I created a vm with virtualbox in windows 7, then partitioned and installed Ubuntu. I'd like to be able to access the vm I already created from Ubuntu-- is that possible?

I've looked around, found one blog post on how to do it but it was for a new vm, not an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you create in ubuntu another Vm? Thats right ? If yes, than i think thats possible.  You can create a shared folder from, 
 Inside ubuntu Vm -> ubuntu vm and from ubuntu vm -> Windows.  You can  connect  Windows and inside ubuntu with a softlink. 'ln -s' 
In ubuntu's shared folder where windows has Access: create a link in ubuntu vm to the path where inside ubuntu's Vm shared folder was mounted!

I hope that you understand what i mean! :)

Comment: Nope, Ubuntu was installed on a partition on my hard drive.

Comment: you must access the filesystem of ubuntu. you can try this tool: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-read-ext3ext4-linux-partition-from-windows-7.html ; you can read ext filessystems of linux. But for thing such like that, i create a third partition, that windows&linux can read e.g: fat32. and save all my things in this partition. Than its possible to access from windows&linux!

Comment: I tried mounting Windows and accessing it from there, tried exporting it from windows and importing it in Linux, and neither worked.